# Bone unwanted rotation when moving IK

Tags: rigging, transforms, bones

I'm making a rig from this tutorial: http://vimeo.com/30078317
And i have problem like this:

[image: gif]

As the title says and GIF shows it is probably a problem with IK, but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your pole-target bone in front of the knee, when you've done the setup as in the tutorial at 19:30 this should work. The IK solver tries to maintain the orientation of the knee to the pole target. That is the reason why the leg is winding .